# VS 2005 restarting when building project solution? How to resolve it?

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2005, application-restart

I getting one issue in vs2005 website project solution.  
 When I start build my vs2005 project in some time vs2005 shows error:- 
 **"Microsoft Visual studio has encountered a problem and needs to close"**.

every time restart visual studio when I started built solution.

How can I get rides from this error?

Any solution.

**Error Message from Event Viewer:** 
*for privacy I changed my project name with dummy*

```
It showing message: Windows cannot access the file D:\MyProject\Bin\MyLib.pdb for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 because of this error.

Program: Microsoft Visual Studio 2005
File: D:\MyProject\Bin\MyLib.pdb

The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.
User Action
1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
    - It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be contacted.
    - It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.

Additional Data
Error value: C000009C
Disk type: 3
```

Comment: Can you check and see if there are any errors on event viewer?

Comment: @DorCohen yes, It showing error. see error message into my question.

Comment: @DorCohen Also show this type of message:- Faulting application start time: 0x01cd553588dab39c
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
Report Id: 39b1b9da-c129-11e1-8271-001cc0ea708d

Comment: Did you try to do all the steps listed on User Action?

Comment: Thanks @DorCohen, I will try and let you know if any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem due to the **.pdb** file.. It getting me issue. 

When I Deleted and Re-Insert (D:\MyProject\Bin\MyLib.pdb) Class Library File(.pdb) into my Web Solution, 
then It worked.

I resolved Issued by delete and Re-Insert file from class library to the web application then Build/Re-Build Solution...

Its Resolved my Issue.

Thanks